# responsive menu toggling module?

Tags: 7, theming

I was curious after stumbling upon this particular construction of a responsive menu.

How was this responsive menu toggle menu created? is it via a module or just pure css / javascript?

http://picturefill7weblinc.h011.attiks.com/node/1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [Responsive Bartik](http://drupal.org/project/responsive_bartik) theme. I can see from the CSS that it uses CSS media queries and from the project description that it uses JavaScript (Html5shiv, Respond.js and Selectivizr.js).